# Iterate over certain columns containing strings in specific rows panas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing 43 columns and i want to iterate only over 3 columns (C, D, E) if value in `column A` is `1,5`. Those 3 columns contain either really complex `sentences` or `NaN`. I want to append `value 1` to `NEW column` to those rows, that only contain `NaN` in all 3 columns while i want to append `value 0` to those rows, if either of columns contain sentence.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
df

A       B        C                 D             E               
1.5     x     grass is green      NaN           NaN                            
1       y       NaN             ball is red     NaN
1.5     z       NaN               NaN           NaN
```

I suppose the beggining of the code should look something like this:

```
 for rating in df['A']:
      if rating == 1.5:
      for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
          print (row["C"], row["D"], row["E"]
```

What would be a possible solution to get result looking like this:

```
df

A       B        C                 D             E               NEW column
1.5     x     grass is green      NaN           NaN                 0            
1       y       NaN             ball is red     NaN
1.5     z       NaN               NaN           NaN                 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rule in pandas should be dont loop if exist vectorized alternative like here.

So use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with masks - first compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==`, second test if all rows has missing values by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and set new values by list:

```
m1 = df['A'].eq(1.5)
m2 = df[['C','D','E']].isna().all(axis=1)

df['new'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2], [1,0], default=np.nan)
print (df)

     A  B               C            D   E  new
0  1.5  x  grass is green          NaN NaN  0.0
1  1.0  y             NaN  ball is red NaN  NaN
2  1.5  z             NaN          NaN NaN  1.0
```

If possible mixing numeric with empty strings (not recommended, but possible):

```
df['new'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2], [1,0], default='')
print (df)
     A  B               C            D   E new
0  1.5  x  grass is green          NaN NaN   0
1  1.0  y             NaN  ball is red NaN    
2  1.5  z             NaN          NaN NaN   1
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Can you please explain what does this part in appending values to df['new'] mean:    np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2] ?

Comment: @Kuki - It means `m1` and `m2` chained by `AND` and for `m1 & ~m2` menas `m1` and inverted mask `m2` chained by `AND`

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and populate the `NEW column` based on the mentioned conditions:

```
m1 = df.A.eq(1.5) 
m2=df[['C', 'D', 'E']].isna().all(1)

df['NEW column'] = np.where(m1, (m1&m2).view('i1'), '')
```

---

```
print(df)

     A  B             C          D   E NEW column
0  1,5  x  grassisgreen        NaN NaN          0
1    1  y           NaN  ballisred NaN           
2  1,5  z           NaN        NaN NaN          1
​
```